# Change the Identity of a JBOSS server in a cluster

Tags: cluster, jboss

I am trying to add an additional JBOSS server to a cluster.  Currently, I just copied over an existing server's directory.  Even after changing some basic parameters such as name etc, I noticed that the

jboss.identity

file still contains the old servers GUID.  Some research

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/docs/guide/2.2/html/ch03.html

shows that this is generated when a server is first brought online from scratch, but nothing on how to change this.  Is there a way to update this so it will be viewed as a unique server in the cluster, or am I better of just taking a fresh Install and configuring from there.

Currently using JBOSS4 on RHEL4 64-bit.